# Different Order of Magnitude on Distinct Interval Plot Axes

Tags: plotting

I have a function as defined below:

```
y[x_] := 9*10^-9*(Exp[x/(2*23*10^-3)] - 1)
```

I am trying to plot this function for the range `-40<=x<0.7`, but in the range `[-40,0]`, the function has very small values so they are not visible when displayed with the values in the interval `[0,0.7]`.

Actually, I want to put `10^-9` order of magnitude for `y[x]<=0` corresponding to `x<=0`, and `10^-3` for `0<=y[x]` which corresponding to `0<=x<0.7`.

I'd also like to make the ticks on the positive `y` axis display whole numbers `1, 2, 3, ....` and scale them by a factor of `10^-3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Module[{f, p1, p2, opts, labels, nlist}, 
 f[x_] := 9*10^-9*(Exp[x/(2*23*10^-3)] - 1);
 opts = {Frame -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
         FrameTicks -> {{labels, None}, {Automatic, None}}};
 nlist = Range[-2*^-8, 0, 0.5*^-8];
 labels = 
  Riffle[nlist, 
    StringJoin[ToString[#], 
       "*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-9\)]\)"] & /@ 
     Round[10*^9 nlist]]~Partition~2;
 p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -40, -2}, Evaluate@opts];
 nlist = Range[0, 0.001, 0.0001];
 labels = 
  Riffle[nlist, 
    StringJoin[ToString[#], 
       "*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)"] & /@ 
     Round[10*^3 nlist]]~Partition~2;
 p2 = Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 1}, Evaluate@opts];
 GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}}]]
```

[image]